# How to check position of a character in a string in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to check if a string contain a letter 'b' after letter 'a'?

For example :

- if the string is 'abcd' then it's return 'true'
- if the string is 'acbd' then it's return 'true'
- if the string is 'bacb' then it's return 'true'
- if the string is 'bcda' then it's return 'false'

Comment: Using a Regular Expression?

Comment: you can simply compare the string whether string contain @"ab" then return true else return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"123abcd";

NSRange ra = [str rangeOfString:@"a"];
NSRange rb = [str rangeOfString:@"b"];

if ((ra.location == NSNotFound) || (ra.location == NSNotFound)) {

    NSLog(@"string is missing one or both specified characters");

} else if (ra.location < rb.location) {

    NSLog(@"a comes before b");

} else {

    NSLog(@"a comes after b");

}
```

Be careful, if "a" or "b" occurs more than once this might not work properly.

Comment: You probably need to work `NSNotFound` into that logic as well.

Comment: I change `NSRange rb = [str rangeOfString:@"b" options:NSBackwardsSearch];` and your answer work for me. Thank you @NKorotkov

Answer (score 0):

You can use if `([string containsString:@"ab"])`

Comment: When the OP said "after", did he mean "right after"?

Comment: I don't know. I assumed that he meant it that way.